Unable to create legacy config file for esling
I'm trying to init eslint for my project and create an .eslintrc.* legacy style config file.
I've tried so far:

pin eslint version to eslint@8.57.0 and run npm init @eslint/config, but it created flat config file eslint.config.mjs

running npm init @eslint/config -- --eslintrc according to the docs, but still it creates the new flat config file


Any idea what to do other than creating it manually?

Running npm init @eslint/config -- --eslintrc seems to create an eslint.config.mjs that imports config from .eslintrc.* file.
Instead, use npm init @eslint/config@0.4.6.
It is the latest version of @eslint/config that creates .eslintrc.* files.
